# Show all the controls of MPMovieplayercontroller always-iphone

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

Anyway to show all the controls of MPMoviePlayerController always.

like below screenshot

[image: Like this]

Any suggestions please

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Look at `controlStyle` property :

> **MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded**
>  Controls for an embedded view are
> displayed. The controls include a start/pause button, a scrubber bar,
> and a button for toggling between fullscreen and embedded display
> modes.

> **MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen**
>  Controls for fullscreen playback are
> displayed. The controls include a start/pause button, a scrubber bar,
> forward and reverse seeking buttons, a button for toggling between
> fullscreen and embedded display modes, a button for toggling the
> aspect fill mode, and a Done button. Tapping the done button pauses
> the video and exits fullscreen mode.

Comment: This is not the answer. OP had asked for a way to display the controls always.